# Python, writing a very basic alarm clock

Tags: python, time, alarm, beep

I've just written a very basic alarm clock in python to warn me when some food is cooked at 2:15pm, but I've read somewhere that time.sleep loses time when other programs are being processed, what should I use instead?
My current code, it's really basic -

```
import time
import winsound
time.sleep(370800)
winsound.Beep(1000,10000)
```

Comment: You could periodically check the time and if it's 2.15pm, beep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do periodic checks. The code below should be ok. You can tweak `timeout` variable to your needs:

```
timeout = 10
target = time.time() + 370800

while True:
    diff = target - time.time()
    if diff < timeout:
        if diff > 0:  # highly unlikely that diff will go below 0 but just in case
            time.sleep(diff)
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(timeout)

winsound.Beep(1000,10000)
```